# Parsing json in jQuery error

Tags: jquery, chart.js

Do not know what I'm doing wrong, I am trying to get json data from and run the code. If I enter the data directly, everything works fine.

**Parsing json (Not working):**

```
function showprice(pricedata){
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(pricedata);
console.log(obj.created);
console.log(obj.price); 

label = obj.created;
values = obj.price;
var data = {
  labels : [obj.created], //obj.created = "2013-12-30 14:20:29","2013-12-30 15:14:48","2013-12-30 14:32:29","2013-12-30 14:26:29" 
  values : [obj.price], //obj.price = 28.41,28.41,72.42,60.42
  datasets : [
    {
      fillColor : "rgba(151,187,205,0.5)",
      strokeColor : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
      pointColor : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
      pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
      data : [obj.price],...
```

[image: Not working]

**Data entered directly into the code (Works):**

```
function showprice(pricedata){
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(pricedata);
console.log(obj.created);
console.log(obj.price); 

label = obj.created;
values = obj.price;
var data = {
  labels : ["2013-12-30 14:20:29","2013-12-30 15:14:48","2013-12-30 14:32:29","2013-12-30 14:26:29"], //obj.created = "2013-12-30 14:20:29","2013-12-30 15:14:48","2013-12-30 14:32:29","2013-12-30 14:26:29" 
  values : [28.41,28.41,72.42,60.42], //obj.price = 28.41,28.41,72.42,60.42
  datasets : [
    {
      fillColor : "rgba(151,187,205,0.5)",
      strokeColor : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
      pointColor : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
      pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
      data : [28.41,28.41,72.42,60.42],
      mouseover: function(data) {...
```

[image: Works]

Comment: what is `pricedata` ?

Comment: Did you try to remove the "[]" around obj.created and obj.price?

Comment: Remove "[]" not work.

Comment: @IstiaqueAhmed see console :)

Comment: Try `obj.created.split(',')` and `obj.price.split(',')`.  It looks like it's a string.  What does your `pricedata` string look like?  What does `console.log(obj)` show?

Comment: Bravo @RocketHazmat!! Fixed!

Comment: @treska, how can console log `priceData` as it is not defined in the given code snippet ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `obj.created` and `obj.price` values are actually *strings* that just so happen to contain commas.

You can convert them to arrays using `.split()`.

```
var label = obj.created.split(',');
var values = obj.price.split(',');
```